# Help with 14.04

Tags: upgrade, 14.04

I'm using 13.10 right now.
And I'd like to upgrade to 14.04, but I can't seem to.
I've tried update manager, and even the iso, but realized I'd need a CD for that.
Is there I can upgrade to 14.04 from 13.10?

Also, I've seen elsewhere that 14.04 will have a final release on the 26th, is that true?

Comment: Correction: The meta-release file has been updated.

Comment: No, 14.04 LTS is already available.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the 'Software Updater' it should tell you that there is a new version of Ubuntu out and will allow you to upgrade, of course I would still recommend installing from a USB or Disk but if you do not have these options then upgrading should be fine.